# JavaScript SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character line 1

Tags: javascript, python, json

In Python I load a variable with data then convert it to json with this code.

```
jsVar = (json.dumps(jsPass))
```

which produces this output. {"TT1004": [[1004, 45.296109039999997, -75.926546579999993, 66.996664760000002, 150, false]], "TT1001": [[1001, 45.296471220000001, -75.923881289999997, 64.616423409999996, 150, false]], "TT1003": [[1003, 45.296109379999997, -75.926543379999998, 67.240025419999995, 150, false]], "TT1002": [[1002, 45.29626098, -75.924908610000003, 65.300880480000004, 150, true]]}

The output passes validation on the JSON Formatter & Validator website. When I run the javaScript code

```
var myVar2 = {};
var myVar2 = JSON.parse(jsVar);
```

I get the following error

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data.

I am not very strong with JS and new to JSON. Any constructive comments, website or literature suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Better Focus on the actual Issue.
From your very helpful explanations and questions I can see that I don’t need to parse the data. As has been stated here the variable holds valid JavaScript array data. What I’m discovering is that the variable generated in Python is not the variable that I’m accessing in JS, even though they are in the same file location and have the same name. The process is set up to run like this. First, the Python code generates the JSON variable, second the JavaScript code assigns a variable with the data from the variable generated in Python and then the HTML file is fired to execute the JS code.  When I look at the output of the console.log or .dir methods for the JavaScript variable there is no data. What I need to learn is how to import the Python variable into the JavaScript Code. I don’t know whether this question can be answered here or should I ask another question in StackOverFlow?

Comment: How exactly are you getting data from python to javascript?

Comment: Is it possible you're being returned JSON already (instead of a string that needs to be parsed)?

Comment: @Hodrobond: JSON *is* a string that needs to be parsed. How else could it be transferred?

Comment: Apologies, I thought there was a possibility of it being transferred as the object, not a string

Comment: @Hodrobond: Yeah, that would require knowledge of the binary representation that the JS engine in the browser uses for the object, as well as a way to import that binary data. JSON exists as a serialization to remedy that.

Comment: ...however it is possible that some API has already parsed it into an object when it arrived.

Answer (score 0):

I 've tested quickly with JSONlint so you definitely get valid json already. There is no need to normalize this with `JSON.parse()` since it is already fine. Only thing you have to do is:

```
var myVar2 = jsVar;
```

If you check `console.log(myVar2.TT1001);` will present you some array data as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is already parsed and you can simply use it like javascript object. if your data is like

```
"{"TT1004":[[1004,45.29610904,-75.92654658,66.99666476,150,false]],"TT1001":[[1001,45.29647122,-75.92388129,64.61642341,150,false]],"TT1003":[[1003,45.29610938,-75.92654338,67.24002542,150,false]],"TT1002":[[1002,45.29626098,-75.92490861,65.30088048,150,true]]}"
```

a JSON string, then you need to parse it but the data you pasted above is a javascript object.

```
{
    "TT1004": [
      [1004, 45.296109039999997, -75.926546579999993, 66.996664760000002, 150, false]
    ],
    "TT1001": [
      [1001, 45.296471220000001, -75.923881289999997, 64.616423409999996, 150, false]
    ],
    "TT1003": [
      [1003, 45.296109379999997, -75.926543379999998, 67.240025419999995, 150, false]
    ],
    "TT1002": [
      [1002, 45.29626098, -75.924908610000003, 65.300880480000004, 150, true]
    ]
  }
```

Comment: What he posted in the question is how JSON would look if it came from a server. There wouldn't be outer quotation marks. Those would only be there if you were creating JSON data directly in a JS program, like: `var j = '{"foo":"bar"}'`. The outer quotes aren't part of the resulting data. They're just syntactic delimiters that tell the JS engine that you want to create a string.

Comment: @squint You are too strict.. :)

Comment: Yeah, I know... :-) Just that people get so mixed up about JSON stuff. When they post raw JSON data in a question, it looks like JavaScript code, so it's hard to tell sometimes what they actually have.

Answer (score -1):

Your data is already a JavaScript object. You can do something like this if you aren't sure whether the object you're getting back is already a valid JavaScript object.

```
if(typeof data != 'object') 
{ 
  var data = JSON.parse(data);
}
```